# Unable to open zip file created with ZipArchive on mainframe computer

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Following is the code written in .Net Core, which creates a .zip file using ZipArchive. The strange thing is it unzips or opens perfectly on Windows or Linux machine, however it fails to unzip/open on a mainframe. Any suggestions or updates, that can be made to the code in order to resolve the issue?

Code:

```
public static async Task CreateZipFileAsync(string zipFileName, string bucket, List<string> pdfFileSet, IAmazonS3 s3Client)
{
    LambdaLogger.Log($"Zipping in progress for: {zipFileName}");
    using MemoryStream zipMS = new MemoryStream();
    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipMS, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var pdfFile in pdfFileSet.Where(fileExt => !fileExt.EndsWith(".ECHOtrig")))
        {
                            
            GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucket,
                Key = pdfFile
            };

            using GetObjectResponse response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request);
            using Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream;
            ZipArchiveEntry zipFileEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(pdfFile.Split('/')[^1]);
                            
            //add the file contents
            using Stream zipEntryStream = zipFileEntry.Open();
            await responseStream.CopyToAsync(zipEntryStream);
        }
        zipArchive.Dispose();
    }
    zipMS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var fileTxfrToS3 = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
    await fileTxfrToS3.UploadAsync(zipMS, bucket, $"{Function.prefix}{zipFileName}");
    LambdaLogger.Log($"Successfully created {zipFileName}");             
}
```

Comment: So you are creating a zip file in c#, then sending the file to a mainframe. And it's the mainframe that is rejecting the file? Have you saved that file anywhere else and tried to check what the file actually contains?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yes, you are right in your understanding. As I mentioned the .zip file unzip/open on Windows/Linux machine (it contains some pdf files) but fails to do so on a mainframe.

Comment: Then I can only suggest that you use other zip file tools to validate the file on both the windows machine and the mainframe. And verify that the file hasn't been corrupted during the transfer process.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Microsoft does not officially support .NET Core on mainframe,

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/supported-os.md

and

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34195

Comment: it looks strange to me. zip should be a standard file format, and mainframe has no reason not to support zip?

Comment: @LeiYang porting to a new platform (CPU architecture) is a very complex tasks. So before someone claims official support on that platform, you should expect all kinds of issues (even trivial ones like zipping/unzipping).

Comment: @LexLi to be precise, it used to work, but suddenly stopped working with an error message `Invalid ZIP Archive`

Comment: i suggest try unzip the exactly same file in windows/linux, or, try other third party zip libraries.

Comment: *zip should be a standard file format* - you think there is only one?

Comment: i know and that is why i suggest other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It's *probably* because the mainframe only understands an older ZIP file version. There have been [several modifications to the ZIP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Version_history) over the years. In my experience, the ones most likely to cause a problem are:

1. 64-bit zip format (usually only used for large files).
2. UTF-8 filename encoding.
3. Encryption and signatures.
4. Unsupported compression/hash/encryption algorithms.